# 'module' object has no attribute 'getusersitepackages'

Tags: python, cygwin

I am going through the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-customization-modules) and seem to be missing something very basic. The tutorial has:

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getusersitepackages()
'/home/user/.local/lib/python3.2/site-packages'
```

But I get the following:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Jun  9 2012, 11:30:32) 
[GCC 4.5.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site
>>> site.getusersitepackages()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getusersitepackages'
```

As it says above, I am running `Python 2.6.8` on `cygwin`.

Is this installation error?

Answer (score 2):

[According to the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.getusersitepackages), this feature/function was added in python2.7 -- You're still on python 2.6

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something pretty basic and stupid.